# Proper way to order query string conditions

Tags: php, mysql, html

How are query strings ordered by hierarchy (in backend).  How do you know which one should be instantiated?  What is a good way to set up conditions for this?  For example in facebook you can have two arguments:
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=49300915&sk=photos
OR one
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=49300915
What is a good way to organize this?
Like would

```
<?php

      if(isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['sk'])) {
    // Query...
    } else if(isset($_GET['id']) {
    // Query...
    }

    ?>
```

- I put the 2 args before the 1 arg so the 1 arg doesn't override the 2 args if the 1 arg isset (weird sentence there...).

  --- How should this be ordered when you have tons of $_GET['variables']?  If I had 5 different arguments that could be passed, How would I order the conditions for which query is fired.

Comment: 5 different arguments = 32 possible combinations.

Comment: Can you please provide an example (with at least 2 or 3 arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of a query string collection should not matter to you. This is not the same as a method signature.

How you deal with different combinations is up to you, and it would depend entirely on what you were doing.

Comment: So, if I had: Site.com?one=1&two=2... would I do if(!empty($_GET['one'] && empty($_GET['two'])))... and do a combinition for each condition?

Comment: @Graham, essentially yes, you would have to deal with all the "expected" / "meaningful" combinations.